# Strahler Order Error

Tags: qgis, stream-order, strahler

[image: Strahler order but the streams are all disconnected]

I'm using QGIS (Zanzibar) for a project in my university and that includes finding the stream order and some shape parameters. So I tried using the `strahler order` to calculate the stream orders and lengths but the algorithm gives me a distorted image which I can't get values from.

P.S.: Using CRS WGS 84 and ASTER map files.

Comment: I think you are looking for the 'Channel Network and Drainage Basins' tool in SAGA for the output you want. It gives the strahler order as an output. The output is vector files of streams and drainage basins. Also, 'Strahler Order' is a SAGA tool rather than a QGIS tool so you already have SAGA installed.